Ambiguity in John 1:12 MSG
But whoever did want Him, who believed He was who He claimed and would do what He said, He made to be their true selves, their child-of-God selves.
The Message translation of John 1:12 seems ambiguous on whether it refers to Jesus fulfilling His promise or believers doing what He said.
Is it:

But whoever did want Him, who believed He was who He claimed and [He]
would do what He said, He made to be their true selves, their
child-of-God selves.

     OR


But whoever did want Him, who believed He was who He claimed and [who]
would do what He said, He made to be their true selves, their
child-of-God selves.

However my pastor confirmed it's the first one. "Jesus would do what He said."
Because the NIV has no mention of believers doing anything so he's interpreting that Peterson is explaining that believers are those who want Jesus, believers believe Jesus is who Jesus claimed to be, and believers believe Jesus will do what Jesus said Jesus would do.
However I'm still unsure.
It could be read either way.

Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question and joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

As the other answers say, the Message intends to interpret a passage in contemporary language. Nevertheless, you do pick up on a nuance which is present. When you read this with John 1:3 in mind, all things include bringing children of God into existence. Not only did Jesus give believers the authority to become children of God, without Jesus no one could become children of God.

Eugene Petersen's "The Message" is written in relation to the intended reader. This type of writing is called "a dynamic or functional equivalence" rendering. It does not use the historic approach to translating the Bible (which is called "formal equivalence").
It was only from the 20th century that this departure began. Instead of measuring accuracy primarily against the original biblical texts, dynamic equivalence is written with a view to appealing to the intended readership. Therefore, modern culture and everyday expressions in language are used. This results in a piece of writing that is akin to everyday conversation. The resulting work is at great risk of becoming subjective and speculative writing.
This is seen in the example given in the text in question. Because it is ambiguous, the way it is written, the question has arisen as to "whether it refers to Jesus fulfilling His promise, or believers doing what He said." The verse is unclear. It is perfectly clear in formal equivalence translations, however. Take, for example this:

"...but as many as did receive him [Jesus] to them he gave authority
to become sons of God - to those believing in his name" Young's
Literal Translation

Nowhere in the entire epilogue of John's gospel does he write about "wanting" Jesus. The verses leading up to verse 12 show what is meant. Jesus came into the world he had created, but the world did not know him. Jesus came unto his own people, the Israelites, but they did not receive him. This means that verse 12 speaks of people who believe in the name of Jesus, and who receive him. To those ones, authority is given to become spiritually 'born' as sons of God. And this miracle of grace is entirely the work of God. That is why verse 13 adds that nothing natural, or physical is involved. A supernatural, spiritual transformation has to happen to those who believe in the name of Jesus, and who receive him in faith.
Much more could be said about the way Peterson has handled the entire verse, but this question is limited in scope, so this answer is limited to what is asked. The answer is simply that the original Greek language states that when Jesus came into the world, those who believed in his name and who received him in faith, had heaven's authority to become spiritual sons of God, by God. They became "born of God", by God, who wills them to be spiritually born. (verse 13).

I may not have been willing to upvote your answer to my most recent Q (re. Rev, 13:15), which you nevertheless acknowledged to the upside but I have no problem upvoting this answer.

@OldeEnglish There is much to be said for either voting, or not voting, according to the merits of the Q or any given answer. Appreciated.

+1 thanks for this erudite answer!

Up-voted +1. Excellent expose of so-called 'dynamic euivalence'. First class assessment. dynamic equivalence is written with a view to appealing to the intended readership.

Peterson's "Message" version of the NT is not a translation but a paraphrase.  It is an excellent version for devotional reading.  However, it has limited use for in-depth and detailed theological study.  John 1:12 is a perfect example of precisely this.
Here is my literal translation of John 1:12 -

However, as many as received Him [ie, Jesus] He [Jesus] gave to them
authority to be children of God, to those trusting in His name

The BLB is similar:

But as many as received Him, He gave to them authority to be children
of God--to those believing in His name

This is not ambiguous - "Salvation is all of Christ and none of us", and John 1:12 is confirming Biblical evidence of this aphorism.  Further, the very next verse confirms this conclusion:

John 1:13 - children born not of blood, nor of the desire or will of
man, but born of God.


Short but sweet! ... + 1.

Upvoted, even though I don't agree that this version is excellent for devotional reading. I see it as a version for children... but I suppose there is something to be said for reading the bible as a child would, even as an old man. ;-)
